# @risingstack/react-easy-state: task is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management, react-easy-state

I'm using `@risingstack/react-easy-state` but often, when I use `autoEffect`, I get the error:

```
task is not a function. (In 'task()', 'task' is undefined)
```

For example this code, suppose I've got 2 stores:

`store1.ts`

```
export const store1 = store({
  values: {}
})
```

`store2.ts`

```
export const store2 = store({
  syncValues: (values) => {
    ...
  }
})
```

Now, in a component, I'm referencing them:

```
export const MyComponent = view(() => {

  ...
  autoEffect(() => {
    store2.syncValues(store1.values);
  });

});
```

The above `autoEffect` code causes the error described in the title. To fix it, I revert to using built-in `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
 store2.syncValues(store1.values);
}, [store1.values])
```

Why am I getting the error when using `autoEffect`? I've followed the [getting started guide](https://github.com/RisingStack/react-easy-state)

Comment: thanks for reporting this, I'm Peter from RisingStack and I'll make sure this gets forwarded as an issue on the repository itself and after the holidays after I'll make sure we are going to allocate some resources to resolve this issue, next time if you encounter any similar issues please post them on: https://github.com/RisingStack/react-easy-state/issues :) Cheers and happy holidays!

Comment: Thanks for looking after this issue! Wonderful library by the way, makes things so much simpler...I hope it could be mentioned and used more!